# Android Studio 3.6 is constantly asking to install a shell script formatter

Tags: android-studio-3.6

After installing Android Studio 3.6 it's constantly showing a balloon to install shell script formatter.

A cropped screenshot is submitted:
[image]

The question is "What is a ***shell script formatter*** and what does it do in Android Studio 3.6?".

It was Googled and looked up in [Android Studio Website](https://developer.android.com) but got nothing.
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may installed plugin for formatting. Check all installed plugin or press "No, thanks"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ran Android Studio as is and with no pre or post-installed plugin(s). My question is exactly what this formatter will do. But after all pressing a button doesn't seem to be a difficult action.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*It was Googled and looked up in Android Studio Website but got nothing.*

Actually, it`s not from the Android perspective, it belongs to the editor we use to develop applications for android framework i.e IntelliJ IDEA.

They introduced this to the script optimized our code structure and provide suggestions to our code like code duplication etc.

[for detailed information](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2019/06/intellij-idea-2019-2-eap2-shell-script-support-improved-code-duplicates-detection-services-tool-window-and-more/)